# How to make Celery I/O bound tasks execute concurrently?

Tags: python, asynchronous, celery, gevent, greenlets

The only thing my Celery task is doing is making an API request and sending the response back to `Redis` queue. What I'd like to achieve is to utilize as many resources as possible by executing tasks in a coroutine-like fashion. This way every time a coroutine hits `requests.post()` the context switcher can switch and allocate resources to another coroutine to send one more request and so forth.

As I understand, to achieve this, my worker has to run with a `gevent` execution pool:

```
celery worker --app=worker.app --pool=gevent --concurreny=500
```

But it doesn't solve the problem on its own. I have found that (probably) for it to work as expected we need monkey patching:

```
@app.task
def task_make_request(payload)
    import gevent.monkey
    gevent.monkey.patch_all()
    
    requests.post('url', payload)
```

The questions:

1. Is `Gevent` the only execution pool that can be used for this goal?
2. Will `patch_all` make `requests.post()` asynchronous so that the context switcher can allocate resources to other coroutines?
3. What is the preferred way of achieving cooperative multitasking behavior for celery tasks with a single I/O bound operation (API call)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run under the `gevent` worker, monkey patching happens almost immediately (see: [celery.**init**](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/main/celery/__init__.py#L109C5-L130)), and does not need to be repeated. This will patch the threading and related concurrency modules. You can inspect this if you get creative fishing in the `requests` library dynamically at runtime (an exercise left to the reader).

You can also use the [eventlet worker](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/concurrency/eventlet.html#examples), and they have a webscraping example in the Celery repository: [here](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/main/examples/eventlet/webcrawler.py)

Comment: Yes, you were right. `requests.get()` under the `Gevent` indeed allows for other tasks to come in.