# How to make Celery tasks with gRPC calls execute concurrently?

Tags: python, celery, gevent, grpc-python

I know that [`Celery` monkey-patching successfully patches `Python`'s `requests` module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76146571/how-to-make-celery-i-o-bound-tasks-execute-concurrently), allowing us to utilize the `gevent` pool to the maximum. Does the same apply for `gRPC` calls?